# Differentiate two views with buttons

Tags: laravel, button, view

I have a view in which I display two data that I take from a table of a DB and next to these data I have two buttons that take me to the same view in which I need to display other things.
What I can't figure out is, how do I differentiate the view AFTER pressing the button?
Here there are the images of the two view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgqe.jpg

The code is the following:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Device;
use App\Models\DataFromRasp;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class DeviceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data=Device::all();
        return view('backend.auth.user.device', compact("data"));

    }

    public function create()
    {
        
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
    }

    public function show(Device $deviceID)
    {
        
    }

    public function edit(Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy(Device $device)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Displays all data present in the table data_from_rasps
     * 
     * The data are all the devices that the raspberry can capture 
     */
    public function visualizeData() 
    {
        $data=DataFromRasp::paginate(10);
        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary', compact("data"));
    }

    /**
     * Raspberry capture and send the data to the DB and save in another
     * table of the same DB the MAC addresses of interest
     */
    public function getData(Request $request)
    {   
        $m_data = $request->get('m_data');
        $r_data = $request->get('r_data');
        DataFromRasp::create(['MAC' => $m_data, 'RSSI' => $r_data]);
        if(($m_data == 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E') and Device::where('MAC_ADDR', $request->m_data)->doesntExist()){ 
            Device::create(['USERNAME'=>'Device1','MAC_ADDR' => $m_data]);
        }
        if(($m_data == '70:1C:E7:E4:71:DA') and Device::where('MAC_ADDR', $request->m_data)->doesntExist()){ 
            Device::create(['USERNAME' => 'Device2','MAC_ADDR' => $m_data]);
        }
    }

    public function scan()
    {
        $process = new Process(['C:\Simone\Università\Tirocinio\laravel-boilerplate-master', 'prova.py']);
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) { throw new ProcessFailedException($process); }
        return redirect()->route('dict');
    }

    public function singleDev(Device $deviceID){
        $data = DataFromRasp::select('RSSI', 'created_at')->where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->get();
        $time_array = [];
        $rssi_array = [];
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach($data as $dataItem){
            array_push($time_array, $dataItem->created_at->format('H:i:s'));
            array_push($rssi_array, $dataItem->RSSI);
        }

        return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("time_array", "rssi_array"));
    }
}
```

View where I select the device:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('content')

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
      <th scope="col">MAC ADDRESS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$item->USERNAME}}</td>
      <td>{{$item->MAC_ADDR}}</td>
      <td>
         <a href="{{ url('admin/singleDevice/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Next time cut needless parts from your code, like the empty methods!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
<a href="/admin/singleDevice/{{ $item->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
```

Instead of

```
 <a href="{{ url('admin/singleDevice/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
```

**Updated!**

I a little bit didn't get what you trying to achieve, but why didnt your try to add another button next to it, to show another view?

Comment: I didn't do it with two views because I didn't know how to differentiate them once the button was inserted.
However, what I would like to obtain is a view which, according to the button I press, displays a graph composed of the data of the selected device.

Comment: I didnt get what you'r trying to achieve. In this case what I saw is you tried to access different page with 2 buttons right? Try to explain it more

Comment: Yes exactly, I want a button to take me to the view "singleDevice/1" where 1 is the id of the device in the DB while the other button takes me to the view "singleDevice/2".

Comment: So what you mean of the other button is, on Device 2 data where there's Select button too?

Comment: Yes, the two select buttons must bring me one to the singleDevice/1 view and the other to singleDevice/2

Comment: Try my code button then, replace it with your button code and tell me what happend.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, it takes me to the same view but only changes the url

Comment: Okay, try to use this in your button url `{{ route('routename') }}`, and try to post your **routes/web.php** file by updating the question.

Comment: The route is: Route::get('singleDevice/{deviceID}', [DeviceController::class, 'singleDev'])->name('singleDev');

Comment: As I see there's nothing wrong with the code, as if you click the button select you should get the singeDevice url with the ID. Try to make another view if you wanted to show another view, then pass it to the button url.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an if statement to determine if one of the buttons is pressed whenever you load the page.

**In blade**

```
<button type="submit" name="device_id" value="$item->id">Select</button>
```

**In controller**

```
$data=Device::all();
$singleDevice = Device::where('id', '=', Input::get('device_id'))->first();
if($singleDevice === null)
{
  return view('backend.auth.user.device', compact("data"));
}
else
{
        $time_array = [];
        $rssi_array = [];
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach($singleDevice as $dataItem){
            array_push($time_array, $dataItem->created_at->format('H:i:s'));
            array_push($rssi_array, $dataItem->RSSI);
        }

        return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("time_array", "rssi_array"));
}
```

Comment: The button does not take me to any view